# SQL Query to Dynamically Display Sales In a Yearly Basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am to make a SQL Query that will display tenants' sales in a yearly basis based on when it started until the present time, unless it is already not active. In the given table below as an illustration, Tenant 1 and 2 display their per year sales. Tenant 1 having 5 rows as it started in 2011, and with Tenant 2 in 2014.

```
+----------+------+-------------+
|  TENANT  | YEAR | TOTAL SALES |
+----------+------+-------------+
| Tenant 1 | 2011 |   1,000     |
| Tenant 1 | 2012 |   3,000     |
| Tenant 1 | 2013 |   2,000     |
| Tenant 1 | 2014 |   3,000     |
| Tenant 1 | 2015 |   2,000     |
| Tenant 2 | 2014 |   5,000     |
| Tenant 2 | 2015 |   2,000     |
+----------+------+-------------+
```

I am totally lost as of now on what to do, I have an existing code that somehow do the same but it is static and not flexible on the years it will display, it is by default 5 years, and it is in vertical form.

```
SELECT
    tenant
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year1 THEN sales END)) AS 'Year1'
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year2 THEN sales END)) AS 'Year2'
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year3 THEN sales END)) AS 'Year3'
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year4 THEN sales END)) AS 'Year4'
    ,(SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(DATE) = @Year5 THEN sales END)) AS 'Year5'
FROM
    TenantSales
```

---

**TenantSales Table**

- Tenant
- Location
- Date
- Sales

Comment: Can you include the original table(s) ?

Comment: Done, already edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing a `GROUP BY` on the `TENANT` and year to achieve your desired output:

```
SELECT TENANT, YEAR(DATE), SUM(Sales) AS `TOTAL SALES`
FROM TenantSales
GROUP BY TENANT, YEAR(DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16b4d3/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @sql =
'SELECT
    Tenant' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , SUM(CASE WHEN [Year] = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), yr) + ' THEN Sales ELSE 0 END) AS ' + QUOTENAME('Year' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), N)) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY yr) N
    FROM(
        SELECT DISTINCT [Year] AS yr
        FROM TenantSales
    ) a
) t
ORDER BY N

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM TenantSales
GROUP BY Tenant
ORDER BY Tenant'

PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Result:

```
|   Tenant | Year1 | Year2 | Year3 | Year4 | Year5 |
|----------|-------|-------|-------|-------|-------|
| Tenant 1 |  1000 |  3000 |  2000 |  3000 |  2000 |
| Tenant 2 |     0 |     0 |     0 |  5000 |  2000 |
```

Comment: No, I want it to be in horizontal, per row form. My posted codes above is also able to produce the same output.

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Comment: I already did, it is in the question sir. the first table posted

Comment: Then checkout @TimBiegeleisen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing 5 separate parameters you can pass one parameter that is ready for pivot statement. This is version when you are passing needed years from some client application. It is not totally dynamic:

```
CREATE TABLE ##t(TENANT VARCHAR(100),     YEAR  INT, SALES MONEY)

INSERT INTO ##t VALUES
('Tenant 1',    2011,    1000),
('Tenant 1',    2012,    3000),
('Tenant 1',    2013,    2000),
('Tenant 1',    2014,    3000),
('Tenant 1',    2015,    2000),
('Tenant 2',    2014,    5000),
('Tenant 2',    2015,    2000)


DECLARE @p VARCHAR(100) = '[2011],[2012],[2013],[2014],[2015]'

DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX) = 'select * from ##t
                           pivot(sum(sales) for year in(' + @p + '))p'

EXEC(@s)

DROP TABLE ##t
```